# handle submit event in directive as well

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I’m quite new to Angular but I love it already!
I need to write a couple of reusable components for a wizard.

I would like to handle the submit event from the form in the directive as well, is this possible?

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" name="exampleForm">
    <foo data="someData"></foo> <!-- I need to handle the submit event in directive as well-->
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

If the user presses enter or clicks the button on the form the directive has to make a call to the backend and double check the data.
If the check is successful the form will be valid.

[I built a simple example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gQgzQ3?p=info)

Thanks in advance!
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

The first issue is targeting the correct $scope. Right now your code targets the `submit()` function on the controller. The `<form>` can't see the $scope of the directive due to how the html elements are nested.

Since you want to `submit()` from the directive, then the directive template should also include the `<form>` element and the `submit` input button.

Invoking foo will look like this:

```
<foo data="someData" name="exampleForm"></foo>
```

If you would rather keep `foo` the way it is (and that's a totally legit way to go about it) then you'll need a new directive with the `submit()` function. So you'd have 2 directives working together (Very angular! Many wow!).

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks a lot for your answer! To be honest I don't understand your answer. I little code example would be much appreciate it. Thanks, Stefan

Comment: Understandable. I'm even having a hard time understanding what I was getting at, lol. No worries though, I have a better answer for you anyway. I'll post it in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

What you will want here is a custom directive for form validation. Custom form validators are added to the `$validators` object on the `ngModelController`.

For a simple example for an "integer" directive (found in the Angular docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) under "Custom Validation"), the directive would be defined like this:

```
var INTEGER_REGEXP = /^\-?\d+$/; 
app.directive('integer', function() { return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.integer = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
          // consider empty models to be valid
          return true;
        }

        if (INTEGER_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
          // it is valid
          return true;
        }

        // it is invalid
        return false;
      };
    }   }; });
```

And it would be used in the form like this:

```
<form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
    <input type="number" ng-model="size" name="size" min="0" max="10" integer />{{size}}<br />
</form>
```

There is also an option for asynchronous validation, adding the validator to the `$asyncValidators`object. More info is found at the link mentioned above. The working example using both is found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ekzHNQen3WpKwoONaEic?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! I have a solution working with asyncValidators but it isn't the best solution. I'm using the async validator to check flight number against flight API. We are paying for every call. Means I start checking after the first 3 characters e.g. "AC8" but the user is going to type "AC8195". (Both are valid flight numbers). In this example the validator makes four calls. I like the idea behind the asyncValidators but in my case it would be better if I could execute the validator on submit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/sckCOq3a50PBjat2uixk?p=preview

I've created another 2-way binding on the directive's scope (called "submit"), so you can specify the name of the submit function as it will be seen from ExampleController's scope (I used "directiveSubmit" here).

```
scope: {
    data: '=',
    submit: '='
},
```

.

```
<foo data="someData" submit="directiveSubmit"></foo>
```

The directive's controller then creates that function and assigns it to its own scope, and that also assigns it to ExampleController's scope via the magic of 2-way binding.

Next you can run that submit function from ExampleController's scope and it will actually be referring to the newly created function in the directive.

```
<form ng-submit="directiveSubmit(exampleForm)" name="exampleForm" novalidate>
```

---

Notice that I'm also passing the exampleForm into that function. Without that the directive will have a hard time getting access to it.

Finally, I've also added `novalidate` to the form because if you don't do that some browsers (i.e. Chrome) will handle form validation in a way that may (or may not) be undesirable. In Chrome try removing that and submitting, then you'll see what I mean (I also made the "name" field required).